# Cant save or run files on spyder, bad file descriptor

Tags: spyder

I cannot run or save any files in spyder, I made a file as simple as print('hi') and tried to save it as test.py, but it gave me an error file not found. If I try to open and save to an existing file it says unable to save file errno 9 bad file descriptor.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is not related to *spyder* but with *Windows 10*.

Windows 10 is not allowing untrusted applications to make changes in protected folders, therefore untrusted spyder cannot make changes (save files) in protected folders.
Here's how to resolve this issue:
1. Open *Windows Defender* --> Home --> Virus & threat protection.
2. Scroll down to *Ransomware Protection* --> Turn off Controlled folder access.

Comment: thank you, what is the risk of doing this?